Cable current ratings
Which of these current ratings is used as the standard current ratings for cable:
Cyclic, Sustained or Distribution.
For example;
A 630mm2 Cu cable (dry XLPE type) has a "Winter SUSTAINED Current Rating" of 841 Amperes, a "Winter CYCLIC Current Rating" of 948 Amperes and a "Winter DISTRIBUTION Current Rating" of 1015 Amperes.
Are we supposed to use the worst case scenario? which would be the "Summer Current Ratings" since temperatures are going to be the highest recorded in the season increasing the resistance of the cable.
For Summer we have, Summer SUSTAINED Current Rating" of 756 Amperes, a "Summer CYCLIC Current Rating" of 874 Amperes and a "Summer DISTRIBUTION Current Rating" of 959 Amperes.
N.B: - this is for a 33kv single core X.L.P.E. Insulated lead sheath & M.D.P.E. Outer sheath cables, laid in PVC duct underground. (Dry design)

All the ratings are used, each in the appropriate circumstance. What you are 'supposed' to do depends who you work for, who you are designing for, whether the cable will be used in summer or winter or both, whether it will be used cyclically etc etc.

Different ratings for different applications. Cyclic rating in cyclic application etc.
